# PHP Mysql Data Arrangement

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me on how to do this[image]

All the data should come from database and arrange like what has show above.Thanks..

Comment: Do you need an SQL statement? What exactly is it you're asking for?

Comment: You need to try and solve this problem yourself. If you encounter a specific problem/issue, then post a targeted question after first checking to see if another user hasn't already asked the same question.

Answer (score 1):

How is this data stored, exactly?

You would ultimately order by the business name and every time a new first character came up, print that as a title.

```
$get_businesses = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM businesses ORDER BY name ASC");

$last_character = '';
while($res_businesses = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_businesses))
{
    $business_name = $res_businesses['name'];
    $first_character = strtolower( sub_str($business_name, 0, 1) );

    if($first_character !== $last_character){
        print '<h1>'.strtoupper($first_character).'</h1>';
    }

    print '<p>'.$business_name.'</p>';

    $last_character = $first_character;
}
```

If it's from your array

```
$last_character = '';
foreach($businesses as $business)
{
    $business_name = $business['name'];
    $first_character = strtolower( sub_str($business_name, 0, 1) );

    if($first_character !== $last_character){
        print '<h1>'.strtoupper($first_character).'</h1>';
    }

    print '<p>'.$business_name.'</p>';

    $last_character = $first_character;
}
```

It's ultimately untested but hopefully it'll give you what you need :)

Comment: the data is something like this Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 21 [name] => Wheel ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 22 [name] => Exterior ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 23 [name] => Interior ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 24 [name] => Brake ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 26 [name] => Lights ) )

Answer (score 0):

This is a concept not the full code !

> **//connect to database**
>
> $sql="SELECT * FROM  ORDER BY DESC";
>
> $result=mysql_query($sql);
>
> while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
>
> **//write a dynamic table here**
>
> echo "< table > < td >";
>
> if($row['name'] == '*Letter name*') //the first letter then go to a new column < br >
>
> }
>
> echo "< /table >";